# Calling wxSizeEvent at the end of sizing event

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have child frame on which I draw an image and when user resizes the frame, the location of the image is updated. This causes some flickering and although I solved this issue to some extent I would like to update the location when user finishes resizing (left mouse button up).Therefore instead of many calls to `OnSize` there will be only one call and that's when the *sizing of the frame is done*.

For example, when Matlab's image processing toolbox is run and the frame is loaded with an image, while user is resizing the frame the position of the image does not change but the position of the image changes once resizing is done (left button up).

I have the following approach but could not make it work:

```
void FrmImageEditor::OnSize(wxSizeEvent & event)
{
    if (IsIconized() || !IsShown()) return;

    std::function<void(wxMouseEvent& evt)> fncBind, fncUnbind;
    fncBind = std::function<void(wxMouseEvent& evt)>([&](wxMouseEvent& evt) 
    { 
        wxMessageBox("Left up"); 
        Connect(wxEVT_SIZE, wxSizeEventHandler(FrmImageEditor::OnSize)); 
        m_UnbindTheEvent= true;
        ReleaseMouse(); 
    });

    CaptureMouse();
    Disconnect(wxEVT_SIZE, wxSizeEventHandler(FrmImageEditor::OnSize));
    if(!m_UnbindTheEvent) Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_UP,fncBind );
    if(m_UnbindTheEvent) Unbind(wxEVT_LEFT_UP, fncBind);
```

The above code does not work in the following ways:

1. Until I click the mouse button (left up) somewhere on the parent or child frame I cannot resize the frame.
2. Even if I resize it, I cannot unbind the bound function as MessageBox keeps popping up when clicked on the client area of the child window.

Is there a way to achieve only one/a couple call to OnSize function (except using static counters in the function).

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you mix Bind() and Connect()? Its probably won't help you here, but...

Comment: Also, for the 2 - I believe you will get continuos message box, because you should probably check for the HitTest, i.e. where did you click the mouse.

Comment: I am using wxFormBuilder to design forms and `Connect` is the mechanism it uses to connect events. If I am hand-writing the event, I tend to use Bind otherwise I just copy-paste from wxFB, so nothing special to mix Bind and Connect. In terms of `HitTest` I think it works in the client area, so most likely it is not going to work here.

Comment: did you test it? I'm sure you need to check what HitTest() is returning and if its border line - you should bind the event, otherwise call `event.Skip()` to let the system process the event.

Comment: BTW, I don't see you calling `event.Skip()` at all. Is it intentional?

Comment: I have not posted the rest of the code for brevity but at the end of the function, I am calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if idle events are generated during resizing, but I don't think they are. If this is correct, doing what you want could be as simple as setting a flag `m_shouldResize` in your `wxEVT_SIZE` handler and checking it in `wxEVT_IDLE` one and actually resizing the image if it is true.

If idle events are still emitted too quickly, you could use the same logic but with a timer event instead.

Comment: I remember trying a similar approach to `m_ShouldResize`. Although it prevented the calls to `OnSize`, the `OnSize` can never be called again when sizing is exactly done (left button up) unless explicitly called from elsewhere using `SetSize` which cannot be called from any of the mouse events (except motion). For some reason, Idle event processing compromised the responsiveness of the frame.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You probably just forgot to call `event.Skip()` in your `wxEVT_SIZE` handler.

Comment: Couple things I fixed: 1) Inheriting `wxScrolledWindow` rather than directly painting on the frame, 2) Binding two events, `m_Parent->Bind(wxEVT_SIZE, &CScrolledImageComponent::OnParentFrameSize, this);` and `Bind(wxEVT_SIZE, &CScrolledImageComponent::OnSize, this);` 3) Using a variable `m_ParentFrameSizeChanged` to track whether the Frame itself it resized.